# How do I convert pt to sp android

Tags: android, android-fonts

i have tried below cosde is working 4.0 but not working in 4.0 above , how to convert pt to sp for setting textview font size.

```
public static int pixelsToSp(int pt) {

        DisplayMetrics metrics = new DisplayMetrics();

        return (int) (pt * metrics.densityDpi / metrics.scaledDensity);
    }
```

Comment: you have to divide by the Medium density at some point.

Answer (score 1):

```
// We need to get some Android resources from conext in order to calculate proper pixel dimensions from sp
Resources resources = getResources();
// Calculate pixel dimension
int pixels = (int) TypedValue.applyDimension(TypedValue.COMPLEX_UNIT_SP, your_sp_value, resources.getDisplayMetrics());
```

I've used this to calculate pixels from dip and it has worked like a charm, but you must have access to context in order to get resources needed.

Answer (score 0):

You'll need access to a `context`.

```
float scaledDensity = context.getResources().getDisplayMetrics().scaledDensity;
return pt/scaledDensity;
```